# Select no MySQL com um array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho um formulario com um campo `multiple select`:

```
<form action="processa-chose.php" method="post">
      <select id="selecionar" name="fornecedor[]"
        data-placeholder="Fabricantes"
        style="width:350px;"
        multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">

        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="envie" />
```

E quero selecionar na coluna fornecedor da tabela os dados pertencentes ao array e então trazer a coluna com os IDs.

Tentei esse script e nao deu certo:

```
<?php
$conect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","XXXXXXXXX");
$fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor'];
$dados = implode(",",$fornecedor);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fornecedores WHERE fornecedor IN ('$dados')";
$result = mysqli_query($conect,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row["id"];
}
?>
```

Essa é a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fornecedores` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fornecedor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

-- Extraindo dados da tabela `fornecedores`
--

INSERT INTO `fornecedores` (`id`, `fornecedor`) VALUES
(1, 'XXX'),
(2, 'XXX'),
(3, 'XXX'),
(4, 'XXX'),
(5, 'XXX'),
(6, 'XXX'),
(7, 'XXX'),
(8, 'XXX');
```

Comment: Seus options não têm `value`! Taí um bom motivo...

Comment: Seria a lolução, mas nao consigo usar o array dentro do SELECT,

Comment: Sua query está correta, basta inserir os values. Por exemplo: `<option value="1">bla</option>`.

Comment: @bfavaretto se for usado o ID como value do option, a cláusula `where` terá que ser alterada também: `SELECT * FROM fornecedores WHERE id IN ('$dados')`

Comment: Verdade, @gmsantos, eu não tinha percebido. Eu usaria mesmo o id em vez do nome.

Comment: Verdade! com id deu certo! só não sei porque ele nao funciona com strings...

Comment: Não funciona porque você está montando `IN('foo, bar')` em vez de `IN('foo', 'bar')`.

Answer (score 6):

Para fazer um `IN` dinamico use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) para juntar/transformar um array em um string delimitador por virgula. Como é um pouco mais complicado passar multiplos argumentos para `bind_param()` foi necessario chamar a função [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) que pega um objeto `$stmt` e aplica o método `bind_param`

```
<?php

$arrPost = array(2,4,6,10,30);

$totalParametros = count($arrPost);
$placeHolders = str_repeat('?,', $totalParametros );
$placeHolders = substr($placeHolders,0, -1); //remove o ultimo caracter, que é uma virgula.

$str = implode(',', $arrPost);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'base');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM fornecedores WHERE id IN('.$placeHolders.')' ;
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

$arrReferencia = array();
foreach($arrPost as $chave => $valor){
    $arrReferencia[$chave] = &$arrPost[$chave];
}

$tipo = str_repeat('i', $totalParametros);

call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'), array_merge(array($tipo), $arrReferencia));
$stmt->execute();
$itens = $stmt->get_result();


foreach($itens as $item){
    echo $item['fornecedor'] .'<br>';
}
```

Resposta baseada nos [comentários do manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score -6):

Eu faria assim:

```
<?php

$conect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","XXXXXXXXX");

$fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor'];

foreach($fornecedor as $value){

   $sql = "SELECT id FROM fornecedores WHERE fornecedor='$value'";

   $result = mysqli_query($conect,$sql);

   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

   echo $row["id"];

}
```

Tambem pode utilizar o mysqli::multy_query()

Comment: Iterar varias consultas no banco de dados é uma péssima ideia. Imagine uma lista de 20 fornecedores, faz sentido fazer 20 consultas ao banco sendo que uma já resolve o problema?

Comment: Depende do que for mais eficiente, ou seja do que for mais rápido e gastar menos recursos do servidor. Aqui estamos a falar de 8 pesquisas. A solução que apresentei tem um loop de 8 ciclos e pode ser feita com 3 variáveis. Muitas vezes para poupar 1 na base de dados, gasta 2 no php. Só testando.