# Como passo parâmetros dinamicos numa preparedStatment?

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu tenho uma função para inserir dados no banco de dados dinamicamente. Ela funcionava bem quando executava a `query` diretamente usando apenas a função `query()`, assim que comecei a reestruturar a função para funcionar com `preparedStatments`, ela parou de funcionar. Simplesmente não consigo passar esses parâmetros no método `bind_param` uma vez que os valores são dinâmicos.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','loja_teste');

function insert($tabela, $args = []){
    global $mysqli;

    $campos = implode(', ', array_keys($args));
    $valores = array_values($args);

    # achar os tipos, dinamicamente;
    $type = $binds = "";
    $i = 1;
    foreach($valores as $valor){
        switch(gettype($valor)){
            case 'integer':
                $type .= 'i';
            break;
            case 'string';
                $type .= 's';
            break;
            default:
                $type .= 's';
            break;    
        }    
        $binds .= "?";
        if($i < count($valores)){
            $binds .= ", ";        
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tabela} ({$campos}) VALUES ({$binds})";
    if($prepare = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                # Aqui onde retorna o erro
        if($prepare->bind_param($type, implode(',', $valores))){
            $prepare->execute();    
        } else {
            die($mysqli->error);
        }    
    } else {
        die($mysqli->error);    
    }
    
    
}

var_dump(insert('tabela', ['nome'=>'Anel de Ouro','preco'=>1000]));

?>
```

Com a função de cima, ele retorna:

> **Strict Standards:** Only variables should be passed by reference in...
>
> **Warning:** mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in...

Mas se eu fizer desse jeito:

```
$vals = implode(',', $valores);    
if($prepare->bind_param($type, &$vals)){
   $prepare->execute();
}
```

Retorna:

> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in...

Alguém sabe como resolver isso ?

Comment: Veja essa resposta: [Select no MySQL com um array](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30181/91)

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo, mas fiz de outro jeito.

Comment: Cria uma resposta com a solução:)

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessas classes: [ConnectionPDO](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO); [ConnectionMSi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi)

Comment: Oi, obrigado pelo sugestão, eu sei que seria mais fácil se usasse o PDO, mas eu não queria fazer muita modificação no meu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionei o problema reordenando os valores, e chamando a função `bind_param` através de outra função chamada `cal_user_func_array` como o @rray falou ali em cima, só não consegui compreender direito, por isso fiz diferente usando a mesma função.

**1º**
Separei a parte que retornava os valores dependendo do tipo, e coloquei tudo em uma função chamada `type`:

```
function type($args = [], $bind = false){
    # Essa função retorna o codigo para o valor 
    # Se o $bind for igual a true, ela vai retornar os simbolos
    $type = $binds = "";    
    $i = 1;
    foreach($args as $valor){
        switch(gettype($valor)){
            case 'integer':
            $type .= 'i';
            break;
            case 'string';
            $type .= 's';
            break;
            default:
            $type .= 's';
            break;  
        }   
        $binds .= "?";
        if($i < count($args)){
            $binds .= ", ";     
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if($bind){
        return $binds;  
    }
    return $type;
}
```

Ela retorna os tipos de valores. Se o segundo argumento estiver como `true` ela retorna os símbolos para o consulta `SQL`.

```
var_dump(type(['nome'=>'Anel de Ouro','preco'=>1000]));
```

> string(2) "si"

```
var_dump(type(['nome'=>'Anel de Ouro','preco'=>1000], true));
```

> string(4) "?, ?"

**2º** Tratei dos parâmetros, criando uma nova função `parametros`:

```
function parametros($args=[], $sec=false){
    # Essa função retorna os parametros já referenciados
    # Se a variavel $sec for igual a true, ela vai retornar  os campos separados por vírgulas   
    $type = type($args);    
    $parametro[] = &$type;
    foreach($args as $key=>$valor){
        $parametro[] =& $args[$key];    
    }   
    if($sec){
        $campos = implode(', ', array_keys($args)); 
        return $campos; 
    }
    return $parametro;
}
```

Ela retorna dados diferentes, dependendo do segundo argumento também:

```
var_dump(parametros(['nome'=>'Anel de Ouro','preco'=>1000]));
```

> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "si" [1]=> string(12) "Anel de Ouro" [2]=> int(1000) }

```
var_dump(parametros(['nome'=>'Anel de Ouro','preco'=>1000], true));
```

> string(11) "nome, preco"

**3º** Modifiquei a minha função original, adicionando a função `cal_user_func_array`:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','loja_teste');

function insert($tabela, $args = []){
    global $mysqli;

    $campos = parametros($args, true); # aqui passo os nomes dos campos da tabela
    $binds = type($args, true); # aqui passo os simbolos (?) para a consulta

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tabela} ({$campos}) VALUES ({$binds})";
    if($prepare = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        if(call_user_func_array(array($prepare, "bind_param"), parametros($args))){
            if($prepare->execute()){
                print "Cadastrado com sucesso"; 
            }
        } else {
            die("Erro (execute): " . $mysqli->error);
        }
    } else {
        die("Erro: (prepare)" . $mysqli->error);    
    }


}
```

Depois executei essa função, usando os mesmos dados:

```
var_dump(insert('tabela', ['nome'=>'Anel de Ouro','preco'=>1000]));
```

> Cadastrado com sucesso

Answer (score 0):

A função para identificar o tipo do campo só esta mostrando `integer` e `string`, fiz umas mudanças porém não consegui identificar o `blob`, ai fiz uma amarração na condição `string`:

```
function type($args = [], $bind = false){
    # Essa função retorna o codigo para o valor 
    # Se o $bind for igual a true, ela vai retornar os simbolos
    $type = $binds = "";    
    $i = 1;
    foreach($args as $valor){
        switch(gettype($valor)){
            case 'integer':
                $type .= 'i';
                break;
            case 'double':
                $type .= 'd';
                break;
            case 'string':
                if (array_search($valor, $args) == 'fd_imagem') {
                    $type .= 'b';
                } else {
                    $type .= 's';
                }
                break;
            default:
                $type .= 's';
                break;  
        }   
        $binds .= "?";
        if($i < count($args)){
            $binds .= ", ";     
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if($bind){
        return $binds;  
    }
    return $type;
}
```