# Salvar array de imagens em colunas diferentes

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Boa noite.

Gostaria de contar com a vossa ajuda para a resolução de um problema que me anda a moer a molécula há uns dias e ainda não consegui encontrar solução.

Eu tenho o seguinte código para efectuar o envio para o servidor de 4 fotos:

```html
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
$selectmaxpro=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select max(`imp_id`) as `impid` from `imp`"));
$maxidpro=$selectmaxpro['impid']+1;

$path = "imo/uploads/"; 
$count = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {


 mysql_query("insert into `images_imp` values('','$name','$maxidpro')");

       
             if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)) {
              $count++;
             }


 }
```

Até aqui tudo bem... o meu problema é que na base de dados os elementos ficam todos seguidos assumindo o mesmo id. Como apresenta a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que raio de query tenho que fazer para que os valores do array sejam gravados em colunas diferentes tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se não for possível, como posso aceder ou seleccionar cada uma das imagens isoladamente para apresentação na pagina? O código que tenho apenas me permite apresentar a primeira das imagens com o mesmo id...

```html
 <div id="imagem1">

 <?php
    
 $selectphoto=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from `images_imp` where `imp_id`='$id' "));
     
 ?>
  
  <img id="targetLayer" src="imo/uploads/<?php echo $selectphoto['imag']; ?>" alt="Image">

  
  </div>
```

Desde já grato pela vossa ajuda.

Abraço
Nuno S.

Comment: Não usa funções `mysql_*`, podes fazer isto com base nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101087/como-passo-par%C3%A2metros-dinamicos-numa-preparedstatment, ou podes ainda utilizar o `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Bom,  o pouco que eu vi desta sua arquitetura, eu achei uma solução mais simples para você conseguir oque precisa.

Como você precisa inserir esses dados no mesmo registro, eu criei uma solução para a inserção de uma vez só, assim, o looping foreach não irá fazer vários registros.

Veja:

```
   <?php 

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                                        {
    $selectmaxpro=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select max(`imp_id`) as `impid` from `imp`"));
    $maxidpro=$selectmaxpro['impid']+1;

    $path = "imo/uploads/"; 
    $count = 0;

    // vamos criar um array das imagens
    $imagens = array();

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {

            // a inserção será feita uma vez só, então retirei o a query de dentro fo foreach

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)) {

                // inseri a imagem no array... e isso sera feito sempre até acabar...
                array_push($imagens, $name);

                $count++;
            }


    }


    // e ai insiro as imagens de uma vez só no mesmo registro...

    $img1 = $imagens[0];
    $img2 = $imagens[1];
    $img3 = $imagens[2];
    $img4 = $imagens[3];


 mysql_query("insert into `images_imp` values('','$img1', '$img2', '$img3', '$img4', '$maxidpro')");

}
```

?>

Como não fiz o teste pode haver algum tipo de erro. Mas a lógica está ai.

Outra solução seria, resgatar essas imagens em looping while

veja:

```
   <div id="imagem1">

<?php

 $selectphoto=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from `images_imp` where `imp_id`='$id' "));


   // com apenas este código ele mostrará todas as imagens que estão com o mesmo 'imp_id'
while($selectphoto){

?>

 <img id="targetLayer" src="imo/uploads/<?php echo $selectphoto['imag']; ?>" alt="Image">


<?php 

// não esqueça de fechar o looping =)

}

?>
```

Como foi citado nos comentários, pare de usar o mysql_query. Use o mysqli ou o PDO

=)

Abraço

Comment: Fabulastico :))  funcionou maravilhosamente @andrei coelho :o) Obrigado a todos pelos conselhos :) abraço

Comment: Tranquilo @NunoSilva .... boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Eae Nuno, Blza?

Tenta usar o [Implode](http://php.net/implode) no seu array $maxidpro, aí é pra ele entender que são mais três campos no insert.