# erro ao passar variavel blob usando bind_param

Tags: php

Boa tarde turma, tenho um sistema para criação de feeds, o qual é possível utilizar imagem, a qual está configurada na base como longblob.

quando passo a variável direto para para a query funciona perfeitamente, mas quando passo pelo bind_param ele da erro.

O erro:
Ele não insere corretamente na base, aparece como arquivo blob no phpmyadmin porém ao exibir a imagem fica quebrada.

estou mostrando assim:

```
echo '<img src="data:'.$feed[0]['fd_imagem_type'].';base64,'.base64_encode( $feed[0]['fd_imagem'] ).'" height="120" class="imgleft1"/>';
```

funções para inserção:

```
function type($args = [], $bind = false){
    # Essa função retorna o codigo para o valor 
    # Se o $bind for igual a true, ela vai retornar os simbolos
    $type = $binds = "";    
    $i = 1;
    foreach($args as $valor){
        switch(gettype($valor)){
            case 'integer':
                $type .= 'i';
                break;
            case 'double':
                $type .= 'd';
                break;
            case 'string':
                if (array_search($valor, $args) == 'fd_imagem') {
                    $type .= 'b';
                } else {
                    $type .= 's';
                }
                break;
            default:
                $type .= 's';
                break;  
        }   
        $binds .= "?";
        if($i < count($args)){
            $binds .= ", ";     
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if($bind){
        return $binds;  
    }
    return $type;
}

function parametros($args=[], $sec=false){
    # Essa função retorna os parametros já referenciados
    # Se a variavel $sec for igual a true, ela vai retornar  os campos separados por vírgulas   
    $type = type($args);    
    $parametro[] = &$type;
    foreach($args as $key=>$valor){
        $parametro[] =& $args[$key];    
    }   
    if($sec){
        $campos = implode(', ', array_keys($args)); 
        return $campos; 
    }
    return $parametro;
}

function insert($mysqli,$tabela, $args = []){

    $campos = parametros($args, true); # aqui passo os nomes dos campos da tabela
    $binds = type($args, true); # aqui passo os simbolos (?) para a consulta

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tabela} ({$campos}) VALUES ({$binds})";

    if($prepare = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        if(call_user_func_array(array($prepare, "bind_param"), parametros($args))){
            if($prepare->execute()){
                return true; 
            }
        } else {
            return $mysqli->error;
        }
    } else {
        return $mysqli->error;    
    }
}
```

aqui faço o insert:

```
// verifica se foi enviada alguma imagem
    if($_FILES['fd_imagem']['name']!=''){
        $_POST['fd_imagem'] = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['fd_imagem']['tmp_name']));
        $_POST['fd_imagem_type'] = $_FILES['fd_imagem']['type'];
    }else{
        $_POST['fd_imagem'] = '';
        $_POST['fd_imagem_type'] = '';
    }    
    $result = insert($mysqli,'tabela',$_POST);
```

PS. as funções peguei do exemplo da Laura
link: [Como passo parâmetros dinamicos numa preparedStatment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101087/como-passo-par%C3%A2metros-dinamicos-numa-preparedstatment/190053)

Comment: Qual erro ocorre?

Comment: Ele não insere corretamente na base, aparece como arquivo blob no phpmyadmin porém ao exibir a imagem fica quebra.

estou mostrando assim:
    echo '<img src="data:'.$feed[0]['fd_imagem_type'].';base64,'.base64_encode( $feed[0]['fd_imagem'] ).'" height="120" class="imgleft1"/>';

Comment: Como assim a imagem fica quebrada?

Comment: Você tem que usar as flags do `bindParam`. E.g.: `bindParam(':variavel', $variavel, PDO::PARAM_STR)`. No seu caso, `bind_param('s', $variavel);`, para mandar como string pro banco de dados. Lembre'se que as novas classes de conexão do PHP foram planejadas para não permitirem SQL Injection de primeira ordem, por isso as entidades HTML e queries são saneadas antes de serem enviadas ao banco dedos.

Comment: Boa tarde Rodrigo, na hora de exibir a imagem ela fica como se não existisse a imagem no servidor, ou seja, o data dele fica salvo errado.

Not The Real Hemingay, estou usando o bindParam dinamicamente através da função abaixo:
    call_user_func_array(array($prepare, "bind_param"), parametros($args))