# Jeito seguro de se usar PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou iniciando com a classe `PDO` e tenho insegurança em trabalhar com a mesma, será que estou trabalhando da forma mais segura (quando falamos de segurança dos dados)?

Sei que há centenas de parâmetros no `PDO`, como `bind`, etc. Mas dessa forma que estou trabalhando é seguro?

**Para conectar:**

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $conn;
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    echo "<br>Erro de conexão: " . $ex->getMessage();
    return false;
}
```

**Para consultar:**

```
if($result = $conn->query($sql))
{
    $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(empty($rows))
        echo "<br>Sem resultados!<br>";
    $conn = null;
    return $rows;
}
else
{
    echo "<br>Sem resultados!<br>";
    return false;
}
```

**Para deletar:**

```
if($result = $conn->query($sql))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    if($result = $stmt->execute())
            echo "<br>Deletado!<br>";
    else
        echo "<br>Query inválida!<br>";

    $conn = null;

    return true;
}
else
{
    echo "<br>Query inválida!<br>";
    return false;
}
```

**Para inserir e atualizar:**

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql ))
{
    if($result = $stmt->execute())
            echo "<br>Inserido!<br>";
    else
        echo "<br>Query inválida!<br>";

    $conn = null;
    return true;
}
else
{
    echo "<br>Query inválida!<br>";
    return false;
}
```

Talvez com `bind` pudesse ficar mais seguro, mas como usar quando se passa parâmetros para função? Dessa forma já está seguro? E há alguma linha inutilizada no meu código?

Comment: Não da para dizer exatamente, o que não pode é inserir variáveis direto na consulta, sobre a outra dúvida veja => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91

Comment: No caso de consulta, estou pegando os parâmetros da função (coluna, where, ordem, limite e like) fazendo um tratamento nelas (como concatenar a expressão da variável `where` com a string `"WHERE"` etc) e depois concatenando todos esses parâmetros na variável `sql`, um exemplo da variável `sql` seria `"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = 'stack' ORDER BY ASC`". Isso seria seguro?

Comment: Depende de onde vierem esses dados que você concatena na consulta.

Comment: Viram geralmente de formulários de outras páginas por `post` (exceto o id que será por `get`) .

Comment: Falas de algo semelhante à isto ? - `$sql = "{$accao} FROM {$tabela} WHERE {$campo} {$operador} {$marcador} {$order}";` - Onde essas variáveis podem ou não possuir funções `SQL` e/ou parâmetros recebidos à partir do formulário, ou até mesmo não possuir valor ?

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso, na realidade, seria `$sql = $coluna.$tabela.$where.$like.$ordem.$limite;` onde `$coluna = "WHERE coluna ";` `$tabela = "FROM tabela ";` e assim por diante...

Comment: Se for apenas isto, não tem mal nenhum, desde essa consulta sql seja gerada corretamente, tendo os campos e os parâmetros perfeitamente organizados antes de ser preparada utilizando o `prepare` ou contendo já os parâmetros todos caso seja com o método `query`.

Comment: Olha [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101087/como-passo-par%C3%A2metros-dinamicos-numa-preparedstatment), ou mesmo esta [resposta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30181/select-no-mysql-com-um-array), apesar de utilizarem o método `bind_param` que é igual ao `bindParam` do `PDO` pode-se conseguir o mesmo feito. Como já antes disse, desde que à consulta esteja corretamente formada não haverá problemas quando fores utilizar o `bind` ou mesmo o `execute([array])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em complemento ao que disse nos comentários, gostaria de acrescentar que escrever scripts na forma procedural utilizando o `PDO`, pode ser um bocadinho mais complicado se estiveres a usar funções relacionadas entre si. Nos exemplos que colocaste na tua pergunta, omitiste a primeira parte em todos os exemplos, deixando o problema meio vago.

Outra coisa é o **problema**. Como tu mesmo disseste, estás  a concatenar partes de modo a obter uma **queryString** final que seja executada sem quaisquer problemas.

Apesar de teres citado *« estou pegando parâmetros da função (coluna, where, ordem, etc) »*, ficou pouco claro sobre àquilo a que te referias, e neste momento continuo a não saber se **coluna** ou **where** são funções individuais ou são argumentos de uma única função. Ao menos já se consegue ver que não estás a utilizar `OOP`, mas continua pouco claro se estás a escrever o código por blocos agrupados em funções ou blocos separados por diferentes ficheiros.

De qualquer das formas irei responder à pergunta com um exemplo, embora tenha feito o uso de funções e tenha quebrado o código em diferentes partes para aumentar a legibilidade ao máximo possível, espero que esta cumpra com o pretendido.

Um factor prioritário é o tratamento dos erros, lançados através de exceções pelo `PDO`, no entanto tratei apenas dos erros durante a conexão com o servidor. Para isso fez-se algo simples, fez-se o uso de uma **closure**, e defini também 2 variáveis cruciais para o funcionamento do script.

**conectar**

```
$prepare = $rows = "";
$pdo = function ()
{
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example;charset=utf8;', 'root', '');
        return $pdo;    
        } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());  
    }   
};
```

A segunda coisa a ser feita, foi a criação de uma função que capaz de executar qualquer consulta `SQL` que lhe seja fornecida, e retorna **true**, caso essa consulta seja executada.

**executar qualquer query**

```
function query($sql, $parametros)
{
    global $pdo;
    global $prepare;    
    if($prepare = $pdo()->prepare($sql))
    {   
        foreach($parametros as $key=> &$valor){
            $prepare->bindParam(":{$key}", $valor);
        }

        //return $prepare->debugDumpParams();

        if($prepare->execute()){
            return true;    
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Até aqui está tudo normal e a funcionar, mas ainda assim, a ideia continua vasta, tanto para os diferentes tipos de consulta - **select, delete, insert, update** - como para as varias cláusulas e outras funções que podem ser executados na consulta final através dessa função `query`. O que fazer é óbvio, **distribuir tarefas**, criando terceiros capazes de fornecer a **queryString** num estado em que a função query terá apenas de executar, independente do que chega através dela.

**executar queries do tipo select e delete**

```
function accao($accao, $tabela, $argumentos = array())
{
    if(!empty($accao) && !empty($tabela) && !empty($argumentos)){
        $campo = $argumentos[0];
        $valor = strtoupper($argumentos[1]) === "LIKE" ?  array($campo=>"%{$argumentos[2]}%") : array($campo=>$argumentos[2]);
        $operador = $argumentos[1];
        $order = isset($argumentos[3]) ? order($accao, $argumentos[3]) : order($accao);
        $marcador = strtoupper($operador) === "IN" ? '(' . parametros($valor, 'param', true) . ')' : parametros(array($campo=>$valor), 'param', true);
        $sql = "{$accao} FROM {$tabela} WHERE {$campo} {$operador} {$marcador} {$order}";
        if(query($sql, $valor)){
            return true;    
        }   
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Esta função recebe um comando `accao` - **select, insert, delete, update** - e analisa os restantes parâmetros para a **queryString** com base nessa accão, e coloca-os como parte dela, assim consegue-se sempre uma **queryString** válida.

Como parte dessa função temos também a função `order`, que resolve unicamente a questão da ordem, e funciona apenas se à consulta for referente ao `SELECT`, caso contrário nenhum parâmetro adicional é retornado - *« string vazia »*.

**ordenar**

```
function order($args, $set = null)
{
    if(strtoupper($args) === "SELECT" || "SELECT *"){
        if(isset($set) && !is_numeric($set)){
            if(!empty($set)){
                $order = "ORDER BY {$set} ASC"; 
            } else {
                $order = "ORDER BY {$set} DESC";    
            }   
        } else {
            $order = "";    
        }
        return $order;  
    }   
    return false;   
}
```

**INSERT**

```
function insert($tabela, $campos=array())
{
    if(!empty($tabela)){
        if(!empty($campos) && is_array($campos)){
            $valores = parametros($campos, 'param', true);  
            $colunas = parametros($campos, 'coluna');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tabela} ({$colunas}) VALUES ({$valores})";
            if(query($sql, $campos)){
                return true;    
            }
        }   
    }   
    return false;   
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
function update($tabela, $id, $campos)
{
    if(!empty($tabela) && !empty($id)){
        if(!empty($campos) && is_array($campos)){
            $campos['id'] = $id;    
            $set = parametros($campos, 'update', true);
            $equals = parametros(['id'=>$id], 'update', true);
            $sql = "UPDATE {$tabela} SET {$set} WHERE {$equals}";
            if(query($sql, $campos)){
                return true;    
            }   
        }   
    }   
    return false;   
}
```

Tanto a função **insert** como a **update** dependem da função **parametros**, responsável por fornecer os parâmetros :nomeados/(?), e também alguns parâmetros adicionais.

**parametros**

```
function parametros($args = array(), $tipo=null, $named = false)
{
    $coluna = isset($args['colunas']) ? $args['colunas'] : array_keys($args);
    $i=1;
    $param='';
    foreach($args as $key=>$arg){
        if(!empty($tipo) && $tipo === 'update'){
            if($named){
                $param .= "{$key} = :{$key}";       
            } else {
                $param .= "{$key} = ?";     
            }   
        } else {
            if($named){
                $param .= ":{$key}";    
            } else {
                $param .= "?";  
            }       
        }
        if($i < count($args)){
            $param .= ', '; 
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if(!empty($tipo)){
        switch($tipo){
            case 'coluna':
                $retorno = implode(', ', $coluna);
                break;  
            case 'param':
                $retorno = $param;
                break;  
            default:
                $retorno = ['colunas'=>implode(', ', $coluna), 'values'=>$param];   
                break;  
        }
        return $retorno;    
    }
    return ['colunas'=>implode(', ', $coluna), 'values'=>$param];   
}
```

A função **select** e **delete** dependem unicamente da função **accao** que faz grande parte do trabalho por elas.

**SELECT**

```
function select($tabela, $campos=array())
{
    global $prepare;    
    if(accao("SELECT *", $tabela, $campos)){
        $all = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $all;
    }   
    return false;
}
```

**DELETE**

```
function delete($tabela, $campos=array())
{
    global $prepare;
    global $rows;
    if(accao("DELETE", $tabela, $campos)){
        $rows = $prepare->rowCount();   
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Para executar qualquer tipo de consulta, seria assim:

> query('SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE nome = ?', ['nome'=>'Edilson', 'apelido'=>'Samuel']));

Para realizar um insert:

> var_dump(insert('jogos', ['nome'=>'Something Awful', 'console'=>'XBOX']));

Para realizar um update:

> var_dump(update('jogos', 17, ['nome'=>'Something Creepy', 'console'=>'XBOX']));

Para realizar um select:

> var_dump(select('jogos', ['id','>', '10']));

Para realizar um delete:

> var_dump(delete('jogo', ['id','=', '18']));

Na consulta com o **delete** utilizou-se a variável `$rows` para armazenar o número de consultas removidas, e esse valor pode ser lido normalmente.

```
if(!empty($rows)){
    print "Removidos:" . $rows; 
}
```

Apesar de ser um exemplo extenso, pode-se ver como vários tipos de consulta são formadas, através de vários parâmetros que podem ou não variar consoante o tipo de consulta solicitada.  Todas as consultas têm como termino a função **query**, onde os valores/variáveis são vinculados(as) aos respectivos marcadores e posteriormente executadas.

Este é um exemplo antigo, com modificações superficiais, e funciona de forma semelhante aos métodos que os framework utilizam, apesar de mais complexos e aperfeiçoados têm um funcionamente semelhante. Uma **queryString** pode ser construída através de processos mais simples, o uso de funções/métodos simplesmente faz com que estes blocos sejam reutilizáveis, e também os organiza.

Comment: Ótima resposta, +1.