# Bind Param com Array - PHP e MySQLi

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Tenho o código:

```html
<?php

$clientes = implode(', ', $clientes);

$busca = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE id IN (?)");
$busca->bind_param("s", $clientes);
$busca->execute();
$busca->bind_result($nome);
$busca->store_result();

if($busca_num_rows() > 0){

   while($busca->fetch()){
    
        echo $nome . "<br>";

   }

}

?>
```

Lembrando que a variável `$clientes` é um array que leva os seguintes valores

> 2, 15, 78, 93

ou seja, quero recuperar os nomes dos clientes com os id's acima.

Meu código até funciona, porém ele só me retorna um cliente (o cliente com o id 2).

Lembrando que tentei da seguinte forma e deu certo:

```
$busca = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE id IN ($clientes)");
```

porém não quero concatenar a variável dentro da query.

Como proceder neste caso?

Comment: retira o `bind_param("s", $clientes)` e muda para `$busca->execute($clientes)`

Comment: Tentei com $busca->execute($clientes), porém me retornou o seguinte erro: Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/.../consulta.php on line 122

Comment: veja se é isso http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: pelo que eu pesquisei aqui, o correto é `WHERE id IN ($clientes)` mesmo

Comment: Sim, entretanto não é uma prática correta de se fazer. Eu estou buscando justamente uma maneira de passar esses parâmetros através do ponteiro do mysqli

Comment: E quando dou um var_dum($mysqli); ele retorna Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77155/discussion-between-wees-smith-and-webcraft).

Comment: faz um teste, se vc colocar o numero de ? iguais ao numero de campos do array da certo?

Comment: [Select no MySQL com um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30181/91) e [Mysqli fazer bind com um array de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101965/91)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Select no MySQL com um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30181/select-no-mysql-com-um-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe um *bind* de *array*, você precisa colocar todos os pontos de interrogação dinamicamente, uma para cada item do array:

```php
$clientes = [2, 15, 78, 93];
$queryParameters = join(',', array_fill(0, count($clientes), '?'));
$busca = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE id IN($queryParameters)");
$busca->execute($clientes);
```